# Mongoid: Filtering nested documents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I am building a RESTful blog API where I have two models:

```
class Article
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  embeds_many :comments

  ...
 end
```

and

```
 class Comment
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :status, type: String

  ...
 end
```

By default `Comment#status` is `new`. When an admin approves the comment, the status will be switched to `published`.

Under no circumstances I want to ship unapproved comments to the frontend.
How can I query all articles with their **published** comments only using one query?

Answer (score 3):

This is what you are looking for

```
@articles = Article.where("comments.status": "published").all
```

read more about querying on nested fields [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/#query-on-nested-field)

Comment: Nope. Here you won't get n+1 issue. It will just look for the articles whose comment status is published.

Comment: This still gets me all comments of any article which has at least one published comment. So if an article has one `published` and one `new` comment - I get the article with both comments.

Comment: Yes it will. Because it embeds all comments inside article object only. When you load article, it will load all embedded documents. if you need to filter it it';s better to make it as a new table and create association with article.